# How should I handle mapping over a DecodeResult?

Tags: scala, argonaut

Often, I find myself with JSON that I wish to parse with strings somewhere inside that I want to parse in a non-trivial way (not just to a String). In such a case I need to make a decoder or a codec for it so I might try to do something like the following:

```
CodecJson[URL](_.toString.asJson, h ⇒ 
  h.as[String].flatMap(s ⇒ Try{new URL(s)}.toOption)
)
```

but this won't compile because I can't flatMap over an Option.

How should this (seemingly common) behavior be handled?

One option would be to decode to an Option[URL], but that seems like a bummer if you just want to fail the decode.

Is there an accepted way of dealing with these subsequent decoding operations?

Answer (score 1):

To solve the flatmap issue, you can convert from Try to DecodeResult. And the following technique also generalizes the String to X Codec.

```
def stringToTCodec[T](toString: T => String, fromString: String => T) = CodecJson[T](toString(_).asJson, h ⇒
h.as[String].flatMap(s ⇒ Try(fromString(s)) match {
  case Success(u) => DecodeResult.ok(u)
  case Failure(t) => DecodeResult.fail(s, h.history)
}))

implicit val urlCodec = stringToTCodec[URL](u => u.toString, s => new URL(s))
```